# Pandas Dataframe resample

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a quite huge dataframe, and i need to average it over 15 second intervals. As you can see the index is not the timestamp, so basically what i need to do is re-sample over column TS (timestamp). Up till now i have been using the matplotlib.dates.num2date(table.index), but this is quite time consuming, and sometimes gives me memory errors. Is there anyway i could use re-sample on and other column? Also if there are any faster way to average every 15th second than re-sample, please let me know. Relevant code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as pltd

>>> table[TS]
735381.370833   2014-05-28 08:54:00
735381.379109   2014-05-28 09:05:55
735381.379155   2014-05-28 09:05:59
735381.380556   2014-05-28 09:08:00
735381.382014   2014-05-28 09:10:06
735381.407407   2014-05-28 09:46:40

table.index = pltd.num2date(table.index)
table = table.resample('15S')
table.index = pltd.date2num(table.index.to_pydatetime())
```

Comment: Why can't you just swap the index with column 'TS'? so call `reset_index` and then `set_index`?

Comment: I tried to use the set_index(TS), but got instant mermory error. (Same when i use reset_index()). So was hoping that something like resample('15S', COLUMN = TS) would do the trick. Or might it be that the table i have opened is to big to do any operations on? If so, is there anyway i can solve this problem?

Comment: About instant memory errors. I don't know about instant, but when performing `reset_index` and `set_index` operations, I always prefer the `inplace=True` flag. This decreases the memory needed to about half.

Comment: Thanks alot! The inplace=True flag, fixed my problem!